# How to get a Mat type object from String?

Tags: android, string, converters, mat

I post a Mat value to server as a String, which contains 2 dimensional array [][32]. Number of rows max is 500. These are values from Mat.
Now, when I get the same String from server, I need to convert it to Mat. How can I do this?

Comment: What 'Mat' is? Can you provide sample of this string so we can figure out what to do?

Comment: [119, 177, 172, 150, 137,  20,  28, 143, 139, 247, 136, 159, 192, 236,  95,  74, 197, 199, 121, 149, 159,  75, 255, 241, 153,  22, 207, 255, 140, 116, 189,  86;]
Like this, but muuuuuuuch more longer.
array[500][32]. can be less than 500

Answer (score 0):

Well Mat has [method put](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/core/Mat.html#put(int,%20int,%20int[])), so we can use it.

```
public int put(int row,
               int col,
               int[] data)
```

So everything we need is convert String to simple int array

```
    String[] arrayString = values.split(", ");
    int[] arrayInt = new int[arrayString.length];
    for (int i = 0;i<arrayString.length;i++) {
        arrayInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrayString[i]);
    }
```

Dont forget you have 2 dimensional array, so you have to parse everything inside `[]` before it.